# Set project in Report Builder 2.0

Tags: tfs, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

I need to build a report in Report Builder 2.0

The report is finished, but we use the report to view open issues and bugs. The report works fine, but now we need to set the current project ourselves in the report. I would like to pass the current project, or read it out somehow, so the report can be used in all our projects without having to change the report everytime.

So when I open the TFS portal, and select a specific project, I want the report to read the project and build the report.. That way we can use the report in all our projects.

Hope somebody can help me with this! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found it.. If somebody issues the same problem, read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730837.aspx#bkmk_createreportbuilder)